# filtering a list of strings using lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, lambda

I have a list like,

```
old_list=["a_apple","b_banana","c_cherry"]
```

and I want to get new list using **lambda**.

```
new_list=["apple","banana","cherry"]
```

I tried but it doesn't work as I expected. here is what I wrote.

```
new_list=filter(lambda x: x.split("_")[1], old_list)
```

what is the problem ?

Comment: Try to use map instead of filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**Python-2**:

```
In [978]: old_list=["a_apple","b_banana","c_cherry"]

In [980]: new_list = map(lambda x: x.split("_")[1], old_list)

In [981]: new_list
Out[981]: ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']
```

**Python-3**:

```
In [4]: new_list = list(map(lambda x: x.split("_")[1], old_list))

In [5]: new_list
Out[5]: ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
lst=["a_apple","b_banana","c_cherry"]
[i.split("_")[1] for i in lst]
```

Output:

```
['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `map` the list with a `lambda` function:

```
list(map(lambda s: s.split('_')[1], old_list))
```

This returns:

```
['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']
```

Answer (score 0):

By using lambda and map:

```
li=["a_apple","b_banana","c_cherry"]

new_li = map(lambda x: x.split('_')[1], li)
print (list(new_li))
# ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']
```